# Efficient and faster implementation of finding and matching unique values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, pandas, indexing

Regarding the following Pandas dataframe,

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A001', 'B001','C001'],
                                  ['0', '1', '2']],
                                 names=['ID', 'Entries'])
col = ['A', 'B']

df = pd.DataFrame('-', idx, col)
df.loc['A001', 'A'] = [10,10,10]
df.loc['A001', 'B'] = [90,84,70]
df.loc['B001', 'A'] = [10,20,30]
df.loc['B001', 'B'] = [70,86,67]
df.loc['C001', 'A'] = [20,20,20]
df.loc['C001', 'B'] = [98,81,72]
df.loc['D001', 'A'] = [20,20,10]
df.loc['D001', 'B'] = [68,71,92]
#df is a dataframe
df
```

I am interested to know the Ids which include the all the values from a set or list in their 'A' column. Let's define a list with values as [10,20]. In this case, I should get locations 'B001' and 'D001' as the answer since both these locations have the values mentioned the list in their 'A' column .
Further can you suggest a faster implementation since I have to work on really big data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set.intersection` for your calculation, and `pd.Index.get_level_values` to extract the first level of your index:

```
search = {10, 20}

idx = (set(df[df['A'] == i].index.get_level_values(0)) for i in search)

res = set.intersection(*idx)
```

Comment: `set.intersection` is really fast. This implementation on a big data set took 71 ns ± 5.34 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each).

Answer (score 1):

Basically -

```
search_list = {10,20}
op = df.groupby(level=0)['A'].apply(lambda x: search_list.issubset(set(x))).reset_index()
print(op[op['A']]['ID'])
```

Thanks @Ben.T for taking out the unnecessary `unique()`

**Output**

```
1    B001
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

**Explanation**

`df.groupby(level=0)['A']` groups by `level 0` and gives you the lists -

```
ID
A001            [10]
B001    [10, 20, 30]
C001            [20]
```

Next, for each of these lists, we convert it into a set and check whether the `search_list` is a subset.

```
ID
A001    False
B001     True
C001    False
```

It returns a `Series` of boolean values which can then be used as a mask -

```
print(op[op['A']]['ID'])
```

Final Output -

```
1    B001
```

Comment: I think `unique` is not necessary as you use `set(x)` after in the `apply` :)

Comment: @Ben.T thats just in case as OP pointed out it will be a big dataset and real world data is full of these. But I agree you have a point! I will edit it